# I am having trouble capturing the vale of a text area, and saving it into local storage

Tags: javascript, local-storage, user-input

Hi I just wondering if i can get some pointers with my code, I am trying to capture and save the input value of a textarea. I am fairly new to JavaScript and I have been wrecking my brain trying to figure it out. My issue is regarding the saveEntry() function, which isn't complete I have only posted how my code is right now, and isn't causing errors/unwanted effects. Any tips or hints would be fantastic, as I keep getting errors

```
function addTextEntry(key, text, isNewEntry) {
    // Create a textarea element to edit the entry
    var textareaElement = document.createElement("textarea");
    textareaElement.rows = 5;
    textareaElement.placeholder = "(new entry)";

    // Set the textarea's value to the given text (if any)
    textareaElement.value = text;
    // Add a section to the page containing the textarea
    addSection(key, textareaElement);

    // If this is a new entry (added by the user clicking a button)
    // move the focus to the textarea to encourage typing
    if (isNewEntry) {
        textareaElement.focus();
    }

    // Create an event listener to save the entry when it changes
    // (i.e. when the user types into the textarea)
    function saveEntry() {
       
        // Save the text entry:
        // ...get the textarea element's current value
    
        var currentValue = document.getElementById('textarea').value;

        
        // ...make a text item using the value
        
        // ...store the item in local storage using the given key

        localstroage.setItem(key, item);
       
    }

  
// Connect the saveEntry event listener to the textarea element 'change' event
    
    textareaElement.addEventListener("change", saveEntry());
    
}      

function addImageEntry(key, url) {
    // Create a image element
    var imgElement = new Image();
    imgElement.alt = "Photo entry";

    // Load the image
    imgElement.src = url;

    // Add a section to the page containing the image
    addSection(key, imgElement);
}

/**
 * Function to handle Add text button 'click' event
 */
function addEntryClick() {
    // Add an empty text entry, using the current timestamp to make a key
    var key = "diary" + Date.now();
    var text = "";
    var isNewEntry = true;
    addTextEntry(key, text, isNewEntry);
```

I was told to utilise something similar to this code below, but not exactly the same as I need to capture the data value of the user input text, not pre-created data.

```
function createDemoItems() {
console.log("Adding demonstration items to local storage");

var item, data, key;

// Make a demo text item
data =
    "Friday: We arrived to this wonderful guesthouse after a pleasant journey " +
    "and were made most welcome by the proprietor, Mike. Looking forward to " +
    "exploring the area tomorrow.";
item = makeItem("text", data);

// Make a key using a fixed timestamp
key = "diary" + "1536771000001";

// Store the item in local storage
localStorage.setItem(key, item);

// Make a demo text item
data =
    "Saturday: After a super breakfast, we took advantage of one of the many " +
    "signed walks nearby. For some of the journey this followed the path of a " +
    "stream to a charming village.";
item = makeItem("text", data);

// Make a key using a fixed timestamp
key = "diary" + "1536771000002";

// Store the item in local storage
localStorage.setItem(key, item);

// Make a demo image item
data = window.DUMMY_DATA_URL;
item = makeItem("image", data);

// Make a key using a fixed timestamp
key = "diary" + "1536771000003";

// Store the item in local storage
localStorage.setItem(key, item);

// Make a demo text item
data =
    "Sunday: Following a tip from Mike we drove to a gastropub at the head of " +
    "the valley - a great meal and fabulous views all round.";
item = makeItem("text", data);

// Make a key using a fixed timestamp
key = "diary" + "1536771000004";

// Store the item in local storage
localStorage.setItem(key, item);
```

}

Comment: What is the *specific* problem? Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Comment: You mistyped localstorage. It should be localStorage.

Comment: Just FYI regarding your `saveEntry` function's introductory comment, it may be slightly misleading to say "Create an event listener to save the entry when it changes (i.e. when the user types into the textarea)". A `textarea`'s [`change` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) fires only after the element loses the focus, which isn't quite the same as "when the user types..."

Answer (score 1):

You are very close, you just have to make some adjustments here and there!

1. Just as a disclaimer, I had to re-create your `addSection()` function, in order to have it properly working. If you already had one, you could discard mine
2. When we create a new entry, in order to make it distinguishable, I have assigned it the id of the `key`. Before, you were trying to call `getElemenyById("textarea")`, but no element had id `textarea`, which is in fact the `tag name` of the textarea element that you created. Read more about [getElementByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) if you want.
3. I have changed the way the event listener is set to:

```js
textareaElement.addEventListener(
    'input',
    function () { saveEntry(); },
    false
);
```

The difference between `change` and `input` are that `change` will fire only when you are done with the changes and click outside of the `textarea`, whilst `input` will fire everytime that you input something. Now you know, so of course, feel free to change it to what you would like it to behave.

Lastly, I have made the just-created item to be retrieved immediately and logged to console. This will be useful just for **testing**, you can comment out those lines when you are happy.

Beware that the snippet below is **playable**, but it won't actually save data to LocalStorage because of SO limitations, so you won't be able to fully test it on **this** page.

```js
        function addSection(key, element) {
            element.id = key;
            var test = document.querySelector("#test");
            test.appendChild(element);
        }

        function addTextEntry(key, text, isNewEntry) {


            // Create an event listener to save the entry when it changes
            // (i.e. when the user types into the textarea)
            function saveEntry() {

                // Save the text entry:
                // ...get the textarea element's current value
                var currentValue = document.getElementById(key).value;

                // ...store the item in local storage using the given key
                localStorage.setItem(key, currentValue);
                
                //Testing if we can retrieve the item, comment out when you're happy
                var item = localStorage.getItem(key);
                console.log(item);
            }


            // Create a textarea element to edit the entry
            var textareaElement = document.createElement("textarea");
            textareaElement.rows = 5;
            textareaElement.placeholder = "(new entry)";

            // Set the textarea's value to the given text (if any)
            textareaElement.value = text;
            // Add a section to the page containing the textarea
            addSection(key, textareaElement);

            // If this is a new entry (added by the user clicking a button)
            // move the focus to the textarea to encourage typing
            if (isNewEntry) {
                textareaElement.focus();
            }

            textareaElement.addEventListener(
                'input',
                function () { saveEntry(); },
                false
            );


            // Connect the saveEntry event listener to the textarea element 'change' event

            //textareaElement.addEventListener("change", saveEntry());

        }

        function addImageEntry(key, url) {
            // Create a image element
            var imgElement = new Image();
            imgElement.alt = "Photo entry";

            // Load the image
            imgElement.src = url;

            // Add a section to the page containing the image
            addSection(key, imgElement);
        }

        /**
         * Function to handle Add text button 'click' event
         */
        function addEntryClick() {
            // Add an empty text entry, using the current timestamp to make a key
            var key = "diary" + Date.now();
            var text = "";
            var isNewEntry = true;
            addTextEntry(key, text, isNewEntry);
        }
        window.onload = () => addEntryClick();
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="test"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things wrong with the way you're doing things, but you know that: that's why you're here!

- You have a typo: `localstroage` should be `localStorage`
- You create a text area but don't give it an ID. In your `saveData` function you attempt to find it, but you're searching for it by tag name. There's no need to search: your event handler will already have `this` set to the element.
- In your event handler you refer to your function as `saveData()`. This will invoke the function immediately and assign its return value as an event handler. Just pass the function name.

Here's a demonstration of concept for you:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Explore local storage</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <textarea id="txt" placeholder="Enter text and press TAB"></textarea>
    <script>
        "use strict";
    
        
        let txtKey = "someKey"
    
        // Save the data. No need to search for the text area: 
        // the special value 'this' is already set to it.
        function saveEntry() {
            localStorage.setItem(txtKey, this.value);
        }
        
        // Look fr the previous text and if it exists, put it in the textarea
        let storedText = localStorage.getItem(txtKey);
        if (storedText) {
            document.getElementById('txt').value = storedText;
        }
        
        // Now add the event listener. 
        tArea.addEventListener('change', saveEntry);   // Pass just the function name
    
    </script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

This code uses a hard-coded value for `txtKey`. Your code might need to generate and track some value for the key, otherwise you risk overwriting earlier data with later data.